# How to enable automatic search results in WordPress

Tags: pages, search

I'm trying to find way to enable automatic search in WP. For example, I have a page `mysite.com/some-thing`. Within that webpage, I also want to display the content of the page `mysite.com/?=some+thing`. I don't want to use an `iframe` because I want the content of the second page (the search page) to be in the HTML source code of the first page.

Is this possible to achieve? I'm thinking about using WP web scraper plugin, but it is difficult to implement the selector :-(

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this in your page template, ideally after endwhile (if any)

```
<?php 
$theQuery = strtolower(trim(get_the_title()));
$args = ('s='.$theQuery .'&showposts=5');
$search_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($search_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($search_query->have_posts()) : 
        $search_query->the_post();

        //do your stuff

    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Gembel. Thank you very much for your great codes, but i'm haven't been able to use it. Could you fill-in a sample example in `do your stuff` section. Since i'm not quite sure what variable is the search content stored in.

Comment: Okay, i have know how to use it now. Thanks. I could not use it because the post i was testing have no search result

Comment: theQuery take page title, you can change $theQuery = 'a'; as a test to see the codes work